# Media query instead of standard css

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Really I didn'y know how to ask this question. But if  I need to do responsive site why should I write CSS and only then media queries if I can write necessary styles in appropriate ranges in media queries at once while making the base of the site in HTML???

Comment: Welcome to SO if you have no idea how to ask a question you need to read this > https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Explain more, what you want to know? What issue you have?

Comment: Whether I can write all the css styles from the very beginning in the media queries or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but I believe you are asking why not just write all your css inside of media queries, rather than some "normal" css then media queries targeting devices afterwards.

The "normal" css is the default that applies to all view port ranges, both large and small.  Media queries are then used to modify or override any of the defaults as necessary for various widths.

If you don't use the default css, then you likely will be duplicating a lot of the same css properties over and over in all of the various media queries. This will make your css bloated and harder to maintain. Usually things like font and background colors, font families, etc are all defined in the base css in one place.  If you were to repeat those over and over in various media queries, besides causing a lot of unnecessary redundancy, if you decided to change a color or font, you would have to change it in lot of places rather than just one.

In designing "mobile first" generally you want your base styles to reflect how you want your site to look on mobile, and then add the media queries to change layout for larger devices moving from the smallest to largest.   That is not to say that you don't use media queries to target the smallest devices, 
but starting with the base css and targeting mobile is considered a best practice.

Also you don't have to write all your base css first (for your entire site) then your media queries after.  But you should write your base css for a element or set of elements first then modify that with the media queries as needed.